# How to ensure ffmpeg transcodes with a speed above 1x

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-encoding

I am trying to stream tv using hls. My setup is ffmpeg and nginx(with nginx-tx module for hls streaming). I am using the command below to scale the video to a height of 320, and sharpening it using default values. I am using the command below.

```
ffmpeg -report -f mpegts -i <input> -vf "scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:320,unsharp=lx=3:ly=3:la=1.0" -vcodec libx264 -crf 24 -preset medium -acodec aac -b:a 50k -f mpegts <output>
```

The issue is that this command gives me different speeds. Initially it starts high e.g. 5x then slows down to 0.6x. When I restart it after sometime, it would start high then slow down but remain above 1x. So, how do I ensure that the speed will always be above 1x?

If the speed gets below 1x, my live stream doesn't work that well, videojs which I use on the browser keeps buffering.

Edit: I should also say that since I am streaming 3 different channels, I have 3 instances of ffmpeg running. The first one is ok, always above 1x. But the latter ones are where I have issues with non-deterministic behaviour(sometimes >1x, others <1x in speed)

Any ideas?

Comment: It's probably the unsharp. Remove it and check the speed.

Comment: @Gyan. If I remove the unsharp, I get a blurred video and the speed still goes below 1x i.e. currently at 0.8x

Comment: Switch to preset veryfast

Comment: @Gyan I tried that too - no change.

Comment: Are you perhaps limited by I/O?

Comment: @slhck I am not sure about that. How would I go about checking that out?

Comment: Where are you writing the output? Is it perhaps a slow, spinning disk? If you check your CPU usage, perhaps the encoding isn't even using 100%, so slowness might be caused by the disk write being at the maximum of what the system/hardware supports. You can check e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55212/how-can-i-monitor-disk-io